# black box function with 2 variable input optimization

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization

I have a black box model which takes 2 inputs, let's say a and b, does calculation and gives me an output, let's say X. What I would like to do is find a and b so that X is the minimum after doing as few iterations as possible. I'm new to such kind of black box optimization problems with multiple variables. Can somebody advise me the route to take? I guess I need some kind of search algorithm to define the function (exploration) and then do optimization on it (genetic algorithm..). Am I in the right direction?

Comment: If the domain (input) of `a` and `b` be unbounded, then this would complicate the problem even further.

Comment: Search for `Derivative-Free Optimization`.

Comment: a and b have bounds, both from 0.8 to 1.2

Comment: Do you know anything about the calculation that results in X? Is it a continuous function? Can there be multiple peaks and troughs?

Comment: I've tried exploring the domain and I see that it is not continues, as you say have several peaks and down. The calculation is done by a commercial software thus no source code is available to know what exact calculations are performed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is theoretically possible without knowing more about the function. Even if you checked 99% of all possible values of a and b, there could still be a small but deep trough in the other 1% that has the smallest value for X. You'd need to know e.g. the maximum slope of value X to be able to discard certain areas in the map.